# Автотест с засеканием времени авторизации

Tags: java, test-automation

Мне необходимо написать автотест на Java для вычисления времени авторизации на сайт. Что если, к примеру, авторизация занимает более 10 секунд, то выдавать в консоль предупреждение.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, идеи по реализации данного теста?

Answer (score 2):

Первое что приходит в голову, это через 10 секунд проверять наличие элемента на страничке, который отображается только тогда, когда пользователь залогинился.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/86480)

Comment: @Denis Спрашиваются, ведь, идеи? Вот я ее и написал :)